# How to Get the checked item which are cheked from listview?

Tags: android, listview, checkboxlist, custom-adapter

Hi I am trying to get the checked item and store in the db, but when i click on button save to get the size of the item checked getting every time size is zero. When click on item of list when it give the only size of the item checked but still if item is not checked.
So it creating the problem for me help me Thanks.
Here is my Code is

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactDetails>{

    List<ContactDetails> listcontacts=null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<ContactDetails> list) {
        super(context, 0);
        mInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray(list.size());
        this.listcontacts=list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listcontacts.size();
    }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = null;
            if (convertView == null) {

              view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_row, null);
              final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
              viewHolder.txtname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
              viewHolder.txtphonenum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_phonenum);
              viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_check);
              viewHolder.checkbox.setFocusable(false);
              viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                      ContactDetails element = (ContactDetails) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                      element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());


                    }
                  });

              view.setTag(viewHolder);
              viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(listcontacts.get(position));
            } else {
              view = convertView;
              ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(listcontacts.get(position));
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.txtname.setText(listcontacts.get(position).getName());
            holder.txtphonenum.setText(listcontacts.get(position).getPhonenumber());
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(listcontacts.get(position).isSelected());
            return view;
    }

     private static class ViewHolder {

            TextView txtname;
            TextView txtphonenum;
            CheckBox checkbox;

        }
}
```

MuListview class is

```
    public class AddChoiceContactList extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{

        private ListView listview=null;
        private Context context=null;
        private DataBaseHelper db=null;
        CustomAdapter adapter=null;
        private Button btnsave=null;

        List<ContactDetails> list=new ArrayList<ContactDetails>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.choicelist);
            context=this;

            listview =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_choice);
            btnsave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_save);
            btnsave.setOnClickListener(this);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            list=db.GetDataContacts();
            if(list.size()>0){
                //listview=getListView();
                Toast.makeText(context, "size is: "+list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter=new CustomAdapter(AddChoiceContactList.this, list);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Contacts Add contats plz!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           SparseBooleanArray checked=listview.getCheckedItemPositions();
 // here m getting size zero when checked then         Toast.makeText(context, "checked size is: "+checked.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           ArrayList<UpdatedContact> selectedItems = new ArrayList<UpdatedContact>();
           for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
               int position = checked.keyAt(i);
               if (checked.valueAt(i)){
                  ContactDetails detils=adapter.getItem(position);

               } 
           }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: when checkbox checked then still give size zero

Comment: It give size when ckick on item and make chekbox checked then it give size but when not make item click and checked then it give size zero

Comment: Where is the code to add checked item in array ?

Comment: Not adding the item in array right now because it gives size zero when checked checkbox

Comment: @sunil check my answer and let me know if you have any doubt..

Comment: @sweetWisher no still problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take a list `ArrayList<ContactDetails> checkedList`   as gloabl and initialize it in consstructor..

Write a method like below in your Custom Adapter

```
private ArrayList<ContactDetails> getCheckedItems() {
    return checkedList;
}
```

and change your checkbox change listener like this..

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            checkedList.add(list.get(position));
        }else {
            checkedList.remove(list.get(position));
        }   
        }
    });
```

And call `adapter.getCheckedItems();` in your `onItemClickListener` of your `Activity`

then you will get the all the checked items..

Comment: position is already there  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) pass that int value and change it to final..

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this.

1. Have a static HashMap on your main activity.
2. Implement two methods over you activity, AddSelection and RemoveSelection
3. On your adapter, implement onCheckedStateChanged listener and, perform either addition or deletion from the map, based on position in list.

In Your Activity:

```
    private static HashMap<Integer,Integer> selectedPositions = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    public static boolean isSelected(int position){
        System.out.println("#### Position: " + position + " Value: " + selectedPositions.containsKey(position));
        return selectedPositions.containsKey(position);
    }

    public static void addSelection(int position){
        System.out.println("#### Puttin Position: " + position);
        selectedPositions.put(position,position);
    }

public static void removeSelection(int position){
    System.out.println("#### Removing Position: " + position);
    selectedPositions.remove(position);
}
```

In your adapter:

```
checkbox.setChecked(MainActivity.isSelected(position));

checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(state == true){
            MainActivity.addSelection(position);
        }else{
            MainActivity.removeSelection(position);
        }
    }

});
```

thats it now, whenever you want iterate through the hasmap for finding out selected items, make sure you clear it when job is done, else u will end up piling selected positions again and again.